# How to add New Attachment field Orange Hrm leaveplugin

Tags: orangehrm

Thanks In advance
 I want Add New Attachment Field before the comment field in leaveplugin In apply leave form How i do please tell step vise

Answer (score 0):

Add this in

```
getFormWidgets()- 
'attach' => new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array('edit_mode' => false,'with_delete' => false, 'file_src' => ''))
```

Add following code in

```
getFormValidators() function -
'attach' => new sfValidatorFile(array('required' => false, 'max_size' => 1024000, 'validated_file_class' => 'orangehrmValidatedFile'))
```

In action class, bind that form with $request->getFiles().

Answer (score 0):

How to add fields in candidate form

First add all threee field in `#_job_candidate` table

1. `orangehrm\symfony\plugins\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\lib\form\AddCandidateForm.php`
2. `orangehrm\symfony\plugins\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\modules\recruitment\templates\addCandidateSuccess.php`
3. `orangehrm\symfony\lib\model\doctrine\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\base\BaseJobCandidate.class.php`

but all data is not Inserted in database